# Getting 404 error when request is made through Alamofire in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

First of all, we are using below code so as the api's works only on mobile devices and not on browsers per say.
"

```
$iPod = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPod");
    $iPhone = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPhone");
    $iPad = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPad");
    $Android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Android");

$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if ($json_data) {
    $username_1 = $json_data->username;
    if ($Android || $iPad || $iPhone || $iPod) {}
```

Secondly, the api's are working on android(using volley) and in ios objective-c using AFNetworking. But, now i am porting the project to swift3 and i am using "Alamofire" for network calls.

Method:: (This is how i make POST request):

```
let headers : HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accept" : "application/json"
        ]

Alamofire.request("API URL", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON{
                response in
                if let json = response.result.value{
                }
```

But, i am getting error 404, which we usually get when we hit api in browser.
After that i removed that backend check and the request worked fine and got the proper response. But, we can't remove that check. So help me, if i am making any mistakes with headers of something else.

This is what i am getting in debugPrint(response)::

```
{ status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 84;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 14 Sep 2017 17:03:17 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.25";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.31";
} }
[Data]: 80 bytes
[Result]: SUCCESS: {
    "is_valid" = 0;
    status = 404;
    "status_message" = "access denied";
    success = 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the User-Agent contains iPod, iPhone or iPad? Read what it seems to send: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/README.md#http-headers. Also, as a debug since you seem to have control over the server, you could check the user-agent.

Answer (score 0):

[Alomafire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) sends a default header parameter User-Agent alright but its value is something like this `iOS Example/1.0 (com.alamofire.iOS-Example; build:1; iOS 10.0.0) Alamofire/4.0.0`.

This is from their readme:
[image]

You can obviously provide your own custom headers:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
  "User-Agent": "iPhone",
  "Accept": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.request("<Ypur URL>", headers: headers)
  .responseJSON { response in
  debugPrint(response)
}
```

Or if you want to keep other default header parameters

```
var headers = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
headers["User-Agent"] = "iPhone"
```

Comment: @karticchaudhary: Can you use charles and see what is getting sent when you make a call from say Android code and your iOS code?

Comment: @PuneetSharma I didn't check Alamofire, but if it use the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` of `NSURLSession`, `configuration` is "copy". And as suggested by Alamofire "If you need to customize these headers, a custom URLSessionConfiguration should be created, the defaultHTTPHeaders property updated and the configuration applied to a new SessionManager instance." CREATE a URLSessionConfiguration and set it to the URLSession. Also, if the author has control over server, let the server search for "iOS" instead of "iPhone", like it did for "Android". The difference choice is weird.